# react change connection to backend to use @cparram/use-redux-api

Tags: reactjs, api

I am creating a react application and I was asked to connect the front end to the backend using this library npm i @cparram/use-redux-api. I am new to react and dont understand how to change my connection.

This is my ActionCreators where I get the data fron the database

```
import  * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

export const addComment = (comment) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
    payload: comment
});

export const postComment = (postId, email, name, body) => (dispatch) => {

    const newComment = {
        postId: postId,
        email: email,
        name: name,
        body: body
    };

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'comments', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(newComment),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      error => {
            throw error;
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => dispatch(addComment(response)))
    .catch(error =>  { console.log('post comments', error.message); alert('Your comment could not be posted\nError: '+error.message); });
};


export const addNewPost = (post) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_POST,
    payload: post
});

export const postNewPost = (userId, id, title, body) => (dispatch) => {

    const newPost = {
        userId: userId,
        id: id,
        title: title,
        body: body
    };

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'posts', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(newPost),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      error => {
            throw error;
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => dispatch(addNewPost(response)))
    .catch(error =>  { console.log('post new Post', error.message); alert('Your Post could not be posted\nError: '+error.message); });
};


export const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(postsLoading(true));

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'posts')
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response;
            }else{
                var error = new Error('Error' + response.status +': '+response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
        .then(response => response.json() )
        .then(posts => dispatch(addPosts(posts)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(postsFailed(error.message)));
}

export const postsLoading = () => ({
    type:ActionTypes.POSTS_LOADING
});

export const postsFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type:ActionTypes.POSTS_FAILED,
    payload:errmess
});

export const addPosts = (posts) => ({
    type:ActionTypes.ADD_POSTS,
    payload:posts
});

export const fetchComments = () => (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(baseUrl + 'comments')
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response;
            }else{
                var error = new Error('Error' + response.status +': '+response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
        .then(response => response.json() )
        .then(comments => dispatch(addComments(comments)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(commentsFailed(error.message)));
}

export const commentsFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type:ActionTypes.COMMENTS_FAILED,
    payload:errmess
});

export const addComments = (comments) => ({
    type:ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENTS,
    payload:comments
});
```

I have tried various ways to do this but get a lot of erros. I am completely lost with this.

When I try to get my posts with this code:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(postsLoading(true));

const [api, apiCall] = useReduxApi('redux-store-key')

    return useEffect(() => {
    apiCall({ endpoint: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' })
  }, []).then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response;
            }else{
                var error = new Error('Error' + response.status +': '+response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
        .then(response => response.json() )
        .then(posts => dispatch(addPosts(posts)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(postsFailed(error.message)));
}
```

I get this error

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: 1. change my connection meaning? 2. Please post only the relevant code here so that others can focus on the problem and not understanding the whole flow. 3. Also post what all you tried and what errors you got (will help others in debugging) 4. If possible create [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: meaning I have to connect to the backend with this library. I am using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ as the backend. I will edit the question with what I have tried and the error I get.

Comment: @Sunil I have edited the question with what I think is the correct way of using this library.

Comment: As per the error, `const [api, apiCall] = useReduxApi('redux-store-key')` is causing the issue. This is a hook and can only be called inside the functional component. You need to fix that.

Comment: So this has to go in my main Component? sorry this is new for me I am new to react so I am a bit lost. This is a link to my complete app https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-night-5cdej

Comment: It should go inside function component. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cparram/use-redux-api the npm page has a sandbox link. You can visit that and it will help you out. It has a working example

Comment: Yes I looked at the example but I am still as lost.